# difference between apex batch classes and java threads

Tags: apex-code

are the batch classes in apex similar to threads in java.
one difference being batch classes can be scheduled,are there other differences 
Please tell the differences..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch Apex is not a form of threading.  You are not going to be add another thread of execution to a class or trigger with Batch Apex.

What you will be able to do with Batch Apex is write code that can perform operations on all (up to 50 million) records of a certain type.  Limitations are similar to other Apex code with a larger heap size and more script statements allowable.  You can only have five batch jobs running at once and cannot generate PDFs from batch jobs.

The only similarity between threading and batch apex is that batch apex is able to run asynchronously to other code in your org.